# MongoDB in OpenVZ VPS

Tags: mongodb, memory, vps, openvz, database

There are some discussions about the problem associated with MongoDB caching in OpenVZ, I was unable to find a practical solution. The issue is related to the memory in OpenVZ, as MongoDB does not consume free memory only. I tried to limit virtual memory by ulimit command, but the problem is that MongoDB server will shut down when reading the limit value of virtual memory (if using unlimited virtual memory, it will shut down when consuming all the machine ram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an 18-month old issue and it doesn't look like any resolution is planned.

[Here's the JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1121).

If you take a look at the ticket, there was a post from 2 days ago that seems to have some workarounds.

Your concept of using `ulimit` will definitely fail. In fact, I've had to manually set `ulimit` to unlimited in version of SuSE just to make it work.